# Define your own semigroup in scalaz

Tags: scala, scalaz

I want to merge two maps in Scala, giving a specific function for combining values.

I really like map1 |+| map2 in scalaz, however I can't find a way how to substitute the + with something else. For example, I would like to pick the max value, or the min value for each key. Ideally, the operator would be provided as an external function, so something of the sort:

```
def op (a, b) = min(a,b)
map1 |op| map2
```

Which would give all the keys with the corresponding min values from both maps.

Comment: What have you tried ? Maybe you could add an example of the expected behaviour ?

Comment: The answer is already in your question. Just define semigroup for the value as you wish, and then import semigroup for Map[K,V] (which would require semigroup for V). If you need specifically min or max, you can do as Huw, suggested, tagging the value, bringing another Semigroup[Int] in the scope. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Map` semigroup uses the semigroup for its value type to merge the values for each key. If you want different behaviour, you can just use a type wrapper for the values whose semigroup has different behaviour.

```
import scalaz._, Scalaz._

val map1 = Map("foo" → 1, "bar" → 2)
val map2 = Map("foo" → 3)

val default = map1 |+| map2
// Map(foo → 4, bar → 2): Map[String, Int]

val min = map1.mapValues(Tags.MinVal(_)) |+| map2.mapValues(Tags.MinVal(_))
// Map(foo → 1, bar → 2): Map[String, Int @@ Tags.MinVal]
```

You can “unwrap” the tagged values with `.unwrap`

```
import scalaz.syntax.tag._
min.mapValues(_.unwrap)
// Map(foo → 1, bar → 2): Map[String, Int]
```

Creating your own type wrapper is straightforward. You simply wrap your type in another type which has an appropriately defined type class instance. For example, if you wanted to create your own version of a `Tags.MaxVal` you could write:

```
case class Max[A: Order](unwrap: A)
object Max {
  implicit def semigroup[A: Order]: Semigroup[Max[A]] =
    new Semigroup[Max[A]] {
      def append(f1: Max[A], f2: ⇒ Max[A]) =
        Max(Order[A].max(f1.unwrap, f2.unwrap))
    }
}
val max = map1.mapValues(Max(_)) |+| map2.mapValues(Max(_))
max.mapValues(_.unwrap)
// Map(foo → 3, bar → 2): Map[String, Int]
```

Alternatively, use can use the Scalaz `Tag` stuff to define wrappers in a similar fashion; see `scalaz.Tag`, `scalaz.Tags`, and `scalaz.std.AnyValInstances` for examples of this.

Comment: How do you create your own type wrapper?